# ORDER BY lowest number

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to order by lowest however this sql term below order's by highest number

```
SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY question_ref DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Make it ASC: `SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY question_ref ASC LIMIT 1;`

Or: `SELECT MIN(question_ref) FROM questions;`

Answer (score 1):

Use `ASC` instead of `DESC`:

```
SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY question_ref ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY question_ref ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ascending rather than descending ordering should do the trick:
`SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY question_ref ASC LIMIT 1;`